# Amateur Bands (400 MHz to 4.4 GHz)

Tags: legal, europe

Could please someone state the open radio bands in which one could transmit:

- freely
- or with Ham Radio license
- and in what max power in each band

between 400 MHz to 4.4 GHz. The purpose of this is to deploy a radar using SDR hardware.

Or at least point me towards an official manual.

Comment: Because this is a question about regulations, please specify your location in the question and as a tag (e.g. [tag:united-states]).

Comment: Telling us about what sort of information you intend to transmit may also help answers be relevant.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about radar, an application of radio that is not Amateur Radio (and besides that, is a "please do my research for me" type question)

Comment: @PhilFrost please. "Amateur radio (also called ham radio) is the use of designated radio frequency spectra for purposes of private recreation, non-commercial exchange of messages, wireless experimentation, self-training, and emergency communication."  From wikipedia.

Comment: @Dimitris'Rafe'Siafarikas so you've read that Wikipedia article which lists the amateur bands, yet you are asking here what they are? Please, show a little research effort.

Comment: @PhilFrost you are right. And sorry about that. I just wanted to verify what I researched, because transmitting in bands that I am not supposed, could lead to authorities at my lab.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few choices in the ISM bands:

- 433mhz (only in Europe)
- 903mhz (only in the US)
- 2.4GHz (worldwide)

Power and antenna rules vary, but the [FCC lists them for the US](http://www.afar.net/tutorials/fcc-rules/).

As for with a ham radio license, it depends on what you mean by 'free'. There are certainly high power ham bands, but you still must abide by the rules of ham operators such as no encryption or musical broadcasts etc so they are not free in that sense.

The [ARRL lists ham bands for the US](http://www.arrl.org/graphical-frequency-allocations).

I am not sure what the regulations are when it comes to homebrewing something to communicate on the ISM bands, building equipment that interferes on them is okay, as their original allocation was to give things like microwaves that inherently transmit a known frequency to use. Intentionally using it for communication is a newer thing and subject to its own restrictions.

Comment: At the list of HAM bands, I can see 420 Mhz and not 433 Mhz? Am I missing something? Also, those three bands are available without HAM operator's license?

Comment: Hi, Yes the ISM Bands, 433mhz, 903mhz, and 2.4ghz can be used without a license. They are independent of the HAM bands. 

How you can use them is specified in section 15 of the FCC document, but that link I gave you gives the gist. If you are somewhere other than the US you may need to look up local laws, but most countries treat ISM bands the same.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band

Answer (score 1):

For the question of which frequencies can be used with an amateur licence, your amateur licence should tell you all this. You have tagged the question as "Europe", but that is a large geographical area with many countries in it.

If you are operating under the CEPT agreements, the CEPT documentation will also tell you all this. Anything I could look up for you using Google, you could just as easily have looked up yourself, especially since you know exactly what licence you have, and which countries this will apply to.

(When you passed your amateur radio examinations, you were told what the bands are, and while you might have forgotten all this, your national radio society will have all the information. Furthermore, there are published national band plans - and the international IARU band plans show you what the 'maximum' range of frequencies are, that are allowed in each region. If you are operating in another country than your own, there are international agreements for which frequencies you can use. These are also available online.)

For the ISM bands, you should have a look at [the Wikipedia page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band).

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your name, I think you must be Greek (I'm also from Greece) so the official band plan can be found here: https://www.eett.gr/opencms/opencms/admin/downloads/Announcments/AP399_034.pdf